# How to disable hardware menu button popup action items on S3?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-menu, android-optionsmenu

I just test my app on a Galaxy S3. It has a hardware menu button on the phone.

I'm using one Activity to hold some fragments, each fragments has their own action bar items to be displayed. It works well on other phone, and just for action bar part, it works well on S3.

My problem is on S3, when I click that hardware menu button, it pop up a list includes all current action items name defined on the fragment. The popup list is on the bottom of the screen. Please see the screenshot below.

I wonder if there a way that I could disable this behavior? I hope the app will ignore the click of hardware menu button, and just let user use the button on action bar. I have tried using dispatchKeyEvent, with check KEYCOD_MENU, but seems not work.

Thank you!

[image]

UPDATE:

For themes:

In values folder, styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="spinBars">true</item>
        <item name="contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.Toolbar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
        <item name="contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Style user drawer -->
    <style name="textView_title_list" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_black_transparent</item>
        <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
        <item name="android:padding">4dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">bottom</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ToolBar -->
    <style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
             <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
             <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
             <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
         </style>


    <style name="SmallTitleText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextAppearance.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
        parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
    </style>


</resources>
```

And in values-v21:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Are you using the support library? If yes, which version? With the latest version, the hardware menu button is ignored in my app on a S2. Maybe you can try to use the latest version.

Comment: I'm using  com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0 AND com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0

Comment: which theme are you using?

Comment: I have updated themes file to the post. Thank you!

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Do you have any solution to this?